# Error 500 service worker response error

Tags: google-chrome, xmlhttprequest, service-worker, jqxhr

I have an upload function with AJAX Progress Listener.

However, some requests failed due to jqXHR.status == 500 and errorThrown is "Service Worker Response Error".

Anyone knows how to reproduce and fix this issue?

Comment: Based on my understanding, XHR does not work with service worker as service worker only work with `Fetch` which is a non-lifecycle event of service worker.

Comment: That's what you'd see if you're using a service worker, that service worker's `fetch` handler calls `event.respondWith()`, and instead of returning a valid response, an error is returned. To answer your question, you'd need to share what your service worker's `fetch` handler is doing.